# Cant clone repo. Server certificate verification failed

Tags: git, ssl, ssl-certificate, lighttpd

when i'm try to clone repository by command

```
git clone https://git.lighttpd.net/mirrors/libev.git
```

I get an error
`fatal: unable to access 'https://git.lighttpd.net/mirrors/libev.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none`

If set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

```
Cloning into 'libev'...
* Couldn't find host git.lighttpd.net in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 5.9.70.195:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to git.lighttpd.net (5.9.70.195) port 443 (#0)
* found 387 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.3 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.lighttpd.net/mirrors/libev.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
```

I can set `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1` but that`s not solving problem

P.S. ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `CAfile: none CRLfile: none` install certificates on your machine.

Comment: debian uses the gnutls curl lib for git (the curl binary uses the openssl one); gnutls checks the ocsp status by default, and it was outdated, because my "restart the server after fetching a fresh ocsp response" config was broken. I used `gnutls-cli -p 443 git.lighttpd.net` to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git clone https://git.lighttpd.net/mirrors/libev.git` works for me (without `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1`) on Fedora 34.  Perhaps you need to upgrade your git package, or the cacerts package on Ubuntu 20.04?

As an aside, lighttpd supports numerous native OS event frameworks, so using lighttpd with libev is unnecessary (and often slightly slower) than allowing lighttpd to directly use the native OS event framework.

Edit: lighttpd.net admin noticed that OCSP status for site certificate had expired and a script was not updating it.  This has been corrected server-side.

Answer (score 5):

As @kamilcuk suggested, be sure to have certificates installed on your machine.

```
apt install ca-certificates
```

Comment: this one worked just fine in ubuntu docker

Answer (score 3):

Setting `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` works for me:

```
➜  ~ GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1 git clone https://git.lighttpd.net/mirrors/libev.git
Cloning into 'libev'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5237, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5237/5237), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1580/1580), done.
remote: Total 5237 (delta 3831), reused 4987 (delta 3656)B/s
Receiving objects: 100% (5237/5237), 1.36 MiB | 2.02 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3831/3831), done.
```

Comment: I'm wrote that it is not solving problem.